# How can I remove or modify the properties of certain decals (Signs/Explosive marks) in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

The black explosive marks on the ground (when a soldier shoots the ground) seem to stay there forever. Is there a command to make them last a shorter time or go away completely?

Further, what's the command to enable/disable the signs around maps, for example the jimie jams and the warning signs?

Comment: You might have more luck splitting these out into separate questions. Also, it would help to know specifically what you want to do with the signs, what specifically are you after there?

Comment: Yeah, I worded that wrongly in my original post, I just want the command to enable or disable the signs, edited that. Also I thought I'd put these together since I figured they would be in the same category or type of commands.

Answer (score 3):

I found out something that may benefit you while researching for [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281589/how-can-i-make-tf2-run-faster). You can reduce how many decals in total that are active at one time using the `mp_decals` configuration setting.

By default, this is set to 200. You can reduce it to be as low as 1 or as high as 4096:

> The maximum number of decals that can exist at once. Decals are used for visual effects like bullet impacts. Higher numbers will result in more persistent decals, at the expense of performance.
>   <sub>[TF2 Wiki - Multiplayer Options](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Multiplayer_options)</sub>

So, if you want to reduce the amount of black explosive marks on the ground, it's likely that setting

```
mp_decals 1
```

will do this for you.

---

There are plenty of other tweakable options/configs and many of them have to do with decals, however not all are well documented, and there are too many to test out. I would suggest playing around with them to achieve the desired result. However, do note that some are considered 'cheats' and thus will not work on Valve servers or servers running `sv_pure 1`. Check out the [List of TF2 console commands and variables](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/List_of_TF2_console_commands_and_variables) from Valve.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer, Robotnik. I played around with some more of the decal commands and I figured out **r_renderoverlayfragment** is the command to disable or enable all the signs around the map.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help point you in the right direction :)